# RSpec mocking, `name` not available from within an example group

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following Ruby code:

```
def report_deviation(departure)
  deviation = departure.fetch('Dev')
  trip = departure.fetch('Trip')
  run_id = trip.fetch('RunId')
  headsign = trip.fetch('InternetServiceDesc')
  timestamp = Time.now.strftime '%l:%M %P'
  FileUtils.mkdir 'log' unless File.directory? 'log'
  File.open DAILY_LOG_FILE, 'a' do |file|
    file.puts "#{timestamp}, #{name}: Run #{run_id} (#{headsign}), deviation #{deviation}"
  end
end
```

Tested by the following RSpec code:

```
describe 'report_deviation' do
  let(:departure) { double }
  let(:trip) { double }
  let(:file) { double }
  it 'appends to a log file with the correct entry format' do
    expect(departure).to receive(:fetch).with('Trip').and_return trip
    expect(departure).to receive(:fetch).with('Dev').and_return 'DEVIATION'
    expect(trip).to receive(:fetch).with('RunId')
      .and_return 'RUN'
    expect(trip).to receive(:fetch).with('InternetServiceDesc')
      .and_return 'HEADSIGN'
    stub_const 'DeviationValidator::DAILY_LOG_FILE', :log_file
    expect(File).to receive(:open).with(:log_file, 'a').and_yield file
    timestamp = '12:00 pm: Run RUN (HEADSIGN), deviation DEVIATION'
    expect(file).to receive(:puts).with timestamp
    Timecop.freeze(Time.new 2017, 7, 31, 12) { report_deviation(departure) }
  end
end
```

But when I run I receive the failure message:

```
`name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

The word `name` isn't written anywhere in here, and if I remove the final line of the test (which invokes the actual code) I get the test failures I would expect for unsatisfied exceptions. I normally would boil my code down to the pieces that are causing the error, but I have no idea what's causing the error.

For what it's worth, the specific line number mentioned in the backtrace is the `file.puts` within the `File.open` block - but I don't understand why that should cause a failure. I've set up test doubles such that those objects are nothing special - `File` receives `open` and yields `file`, whose only job is to listen for receiving `puts` with the string I expect. So what piece of code is calling what happens to be a keyword RSpec method `name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is not a keyword `RSpec` method, it's a method that `report_deviation` is trying to call

```
file.puts "#{timestamp}, #{name}: Run #{run_id} (#{headsign}), deviation #{deviation}"
```

but the method is not defined.

You need to define the `name` method in the class where `report_deviation` is defined. Or, if `report_deviation` is defined and used in the spec file, add a simple variable called `name`:

```
describe 'report_deviation' do
  let(:departure) { double }
  let(:trip) { double }
  let(:file) { double }
  let(:name) { "simple name" }
  ...
```

Comment: Ugh missed that, thanks! That's what happens when I do method abstraction too quickly...

Answer (score 15):

The problem is from rspec gem, if you are using Rails 6 you need to use `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.1.0'`

Comment: To be precise, did not get this error on Rails 6.0.3.1, but got on 6.1.4.6. But yeah, 'rspec-rails' gem was the reason.

Answer (score 2):

> `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) [...]

I had a similar problem today. The final solution for the issue for now with a monkeypatch to go back to using method_name.

Create `config/initializers/monkeypatches.rb` file and fill inside with the following lines.

```
# config/initializers/monkeypatches.rb
#
# This fixes what seems to be a bug introduced by
# https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37770
# "Modify ActiveRecord::TestFixtures to not rely on AS::TestCase:"
#
module ActiveRecord::TestFixtures
  def run_in_transaction?
    use_transactional_tests &&
      !self.class.uses_transaction?(method_name) # this monkeypatch changes `name` to `method_name`
  end
end
```

Credits: https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise/issues/42